# How to install j2sdk 1.4.2 on 64bit linux?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I have a problem with installation of java j2sdk 1.4.2 on 64bit linux (Ubuntu 10.04). Did anybody handle it?

> uname -a
>
> 2.6.32-25-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 17 20:05:27 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I run a self-extracting file

> sudo ./j2sdk-1_4_2_02-linux-i586.bin

but I get

> tail: cannot open `+473' for reading:
> No such file or directory

[Oracle forum](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1319516) has no answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the ubuntu tail command doesn't understand the 'tail +<>' syntax. You need to edit the file, being careful not to corrupt the content that is after the 473rd line, replacing the tail command with 'tail -n +473' instead. This should get you past this problem.

Comment: Glad that worked. It's one of the problems writing a script that needs to work across a variety of releases of Linux - not all the releases support the same flags for the commands. Solaris supports the use of 'tail +<line>' to start from a particular line in a file until the end, and I'm almost certain I used that form of tail on an older release of Linux (by setting _POSIX2_VERSION=199209 before executing tail +<number> it works in this manner)

Comment: With the risk of appearing not very clever :-): I have first tried to do the replacement by editing the file, which obviously corrupted my file, so I have used following command for doing the replacement: `sed -i 's/tail +/tail -n +/' j2sdk-1_4_2-linux-i586.bin`

Comment: @Dominique if it works, then so much the better - it's a lot easier than some manual editing. I'd be tempted to avoid a `sed -i` which clobbers the original file, and send it to a new file, so if the sed didn't work in the first place you still have the original.

Comment: I manually edited the file, which caused the checksum to fail. @Dominique's `sed` solution worked wonders!

Answer (score 0):

You should always prefer Ubuntu's package management system before trying to install software manually.

Is there a reason why you want to install the outdated Java version 1.4.2? It's better to install the latest Java version, which is version 6. Note that Sun Java 6 is backward compatible with 1.4.2; anything that runs on 1.4.2 will also run on Java 6.

Also note that you can use "javac -target 1.4" to ensure that the generated class files will be compatible with 1.4 JVM.

If you really have a special reason to install Sun Java 1.4.2: Ubuntu works with .deb (Debian) packages.

Comment: Yes, indeed I have to install the outdated Java version to fix an existing program. And it has to be compiled in 1.4.2

Comment: Of course I installed JDK 5 and 6 from repository. But 1.4.2 is understandably not there.

Comment: You can use a compiler flag to indicate you want to compile as Java 4. Just do: javac -source 1.4. This is not a reason to install an outdated JDK imho.

Comment: Probably -target, not -source.

Comment: And that may not even be enough, he might need to have the old --bootclasspath and --extdirs. Not 100% sure.

Comment: As far as I know javac -target 1.4 not influences bytecode and does not respect changes in API. It can noticed foreach statement but not ignore "new API" such as java.util.Thread#getId() etc.

Comment: From the manpage: -target version
Generate class files that will work on VMs with the specified version. The default is to generate class files to be compatible with the JDK 5 VM. When the -source 1.4 or lower option is used, the default target is 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

Try "chmod a+x ..."
is this package for 64 bit OS? how abt try to run it on a 32 bit OS?
When you run "sudo ./j2sdk-1_4_2_02-linux-i586.bin", are you really in the same path? how abt try to use absolute path.

obviously, @Jeroen Rosenberg's way is much better

Comment: Yes, I know that "chmod a+x" is a must. Thanks for the idea of the full path but it does not work either. Unfortunately change to 32bit OS is not applicable (or at least to complicated) for me right now.

Answer (score 0):

you could have also temporarily replace tail command binary with a bash script, or alias or something, handling arguments the way you want :)